# Error with package diffcoeff

Tags: errors, diffcoeff

When loading the `diffcoeff` package, even in very basic examples, I'm getting a repeated error that wasn't there a few weeks ago. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\diffdef {}
{
    op-symbol    = \mathrm{d},
    op-order-sep = 0 mu
}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

And here is the error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.sty:138:
Illegal parameter number in definition of \key code > 
template/derivative/DERIV/long-var-wrap/dv.
<to be read again> 
                   2
l.138   }
```

Comment: I'm working on it

Comment: I am discussing with the LaTeX team: the issue arises due to a package change, but that was deliberate and potentially highlights an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the error until an `xtemplate` update this morning. I've amended `diffcoeff` following a suggestion from Joseph Wright and uploaded the revised version (4.1) to CTAN a few minutes ago.

Comment: Perfect, it's fixed now! Thanks!

Comment: @gabo_18:  When I try to compile your code I have exactly the same error: 
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \key code > template/derivative/DER
IV/long-var-wrap/dv.
<to be read again>
                   2
l.138   }

?
This message appears after reading of the l3package/xtemplate file. How did you fix it. My Miktex installation is up to date.

Comment: I think it was fixed after an update of `diffcoeff`, are you sure you have the latest version of the package installed?

Comment: Checking my installation of MiKTeX, it hasn't updated ```diffcoeff``` yet. (Still has v.4.0 rather than v.4.1.) CTAN has the later version.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know how to fix this problem, download diffcoeff.zip from CTAN (version 4.1), unzip it, and copy diffcoef.sty in the folder you are working (the one that has your main tex file). Let's hope CTAN is going to be updated soon with the last version.